# Create 2GP package version with multiple dependency

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, unlocked-package, 2gp

I have below JSON file having more than one package dependency link to single package.

When a package has single dependency it executed without error but if a package has two dependency I am getting error on second dependent package metadata.

I am getting following error over the command 'package88Outbound' has two dependency

**Command:**

> sfdx force:package:version:create --package "package88Outbound"
> --installationkey “package88” --wait 10

**Error:**

> *Type is not visible:*

```
{
     "packageDirectories": [
         {
             "path": "schema-pack",
             "default": true,
             "package": "package88Schema",
             "versionName": "ver 0.1",
             "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT"
         },
         {
             "path": "common-pack",
             "default": false,
             "package": "package88Common",
             "versionName": "ver 0.1",
             "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
             "dependencies": [
                 {
                     "package": "schema-pack",
                     "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
                 }
             ]
         },
         {
             "path": "outbound-pack",
             "package": "package88Outbound",
             "versionName": "ver 0.1",
             "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
             "default": false,
             "dependencies": [
                 {
                     "package": "schema-pack",
                     "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
                 },
                 {
                     "package": "common-pack",
                     "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
                 }
             ]
         },
         {
             "path": "inbound-pack",
             "default": false,
             "package": "package88Inbound",
             "versionName": "ver 0.1",
             "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
             "dependencies": [
                 {
                     "package": "schema-pack",
                     "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
                 },
                 {
                     "package": "common-pack",
                     "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
                 }
             ]
         },
         {
             "path": "visual-pack",
             "default": false,
             "package": "package88Visual",
             "versionName": "ver 0.1",
             "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
             "dependencies": [
                 {
                     "package": "schema-pack",
                     "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
                 },
                 {
                     "package": "common-pack",
                     "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
                 }
             ]
         }
     ],
     "namespace": "package88**",
     "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
     "sourceApiVersion": "49.0",
     "packageAliases": {
         "package88Schema": "0Ho88********",
         "package88Common": "0Ho88********",
         "package88Outbound": "0Ho88********",
         "package88Inbound": "0Ho88********",
         "package88Visual": "0Ho88********",
         "package88Schema@0.1.0-2": "0Ho88********"
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my mistake forgot to add @namespaceAccessible annotation referenced depending package.

Answer (score 1):

I think your JSON is not correct. Whatever dependencies mentioned, shall be present in the packageAliases with 04t***** IDs.

Please check the good article on that -
https://sfdc-db-gmail.github.io/unlocked-packages/faq-unlocked-pkgs.html#complex-pkg-deps

Please try to create a JSON like this -

```json
{
    "packageDirectories": [{
            "path": "schema-pack",
            "default": true,
            "package": "package88Schema",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "dependencies": [{
                "package": "schema-pack",
                "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
            }]
        },
        {
            "path": "visual-pack",
            "default": false,
            "package": "package88Visual",
            "versionName": "ver 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "dependencies": [{
                    "package": "schema-pack",
                    "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
                },
                {
                    "package": "common-pack",
                    "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "package88**",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "49.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "package88Schema": "0Ho88********",
        "package88Visual": "0Ho88********",
        "schema-pack": "04t88********",
        "common-pack" : "04t**********"
    }
}
```